Database locked in PHPUnit tests only
In my application SQLite works. But when I create tests in PHPUnit it's locked on the first write. I've hacked in some beginTranaction() and commit() but it still hangs on the commit() call. The test code creates tables, writes data, and reads the data. The same steps in PHP work fine. Is there something in PHPUnit locking the database?
$kv->select(self::MOVIE_TABLE_NAME);
$title = "Rainman";
$movie = $kv->get(1);
$this->assertNull($movie);
$kv->set(['imdb_id' => 1, 'name' => $title, 'year' => 1985], 1);

The set method (in the actual code the prepared statement is cached):
$statement = $this->db->prepare("
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO $tableName($keyName, value)
        VALUES(:key, :value)
");
$results = $statement->execute(
[
    'key' => $key,
    "value" => json_encode($value)
]);

No matter what combination of closing the connection and committing transactions, it keeps getting locked when writing in the tests, but not in the application.
PHPUnit runs when I add:
$this->db->query("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL");
$this->db->query("PRAGMA lock_timeout=5");
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10);

I'm not sure this is the solution, but at least tests pass now.

Have one database for your application and another for your tests.
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL

That is the sqlite write ahead log. You observed that enabling WAL prevents the locking during the run of the PHPUnit tests ("it's locked on the first write").
This could be a sign, that you are using the same file concurrently (applicate + tests). Therefore the suggestion to have two databases, one for the application and one for testing. This is even good to have as a default project setup.
Write ahead logging can mitigate such problems, nevertheless your tests should have their own sqlite database apart from the application.
This can be solved with a parameter for the database name you can set for each environment or configuration (app/test).
This will also allow you to write better tests covering the things you'd like to do with your sqlite database. From your question I'd assume in good faith that this will also give you more fun in testing things with PHPUnit.
If you have no problem with the additional WAL file, you can continue to use PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL for both databases, overhead is very little (1-2%) and the benefits often outweigh the negatives. But as this is not always the case, have another parameter so you can configure it for your application and within tests perhaps for testing you can have tests that can run in both modes.
For more information read Write-Ahead Logging.
